# How to find the attribute and element id by selenium.webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriver

I am learning web scrapping since I need it for my work. I wrote the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver    
chromedriver='/home/es/drivers/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/hemolytik/submitkey_browse.php?ran=1955')
df = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("table.example.display.datatable").get_attribute('example'))[0]
```

However, it is showing the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="table.example.display.datatable"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

Then I inspect the table that I wanna scrape this table from [this page](https://selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:%20Message:%20no%20such%20element:%20Unable%20to%20locate%20element:%20%7B%22method%22:%22css%20selector%22,%22selector%22:%22%5Bid=%22table.example.display.datatable%22%5D%22%7D%20%20%20(Session%20info:%20chrome=103.0.5060.134))
[image]

what is the attribute that needs to be included in `get_attribute()` function in the following line?

```
df = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("table.example.display.datatable").get_attribute('example'))[0]
```

what I should write in the `driver.find_element_by_id`?

**EDITED:**
Some tables have lots of records in multi-pages.
For example, [this page](http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/hemolytik/submitkey_browse.php?ran=4540) has 2,246 entries, which shows 100 entries on each page. Once I tried to web-scrape it, there were only 320 entries in `df` and the record ID is from 1232-1713, which means it took entries from the next few pages and it is not starting from the first page to the end at the last page.

What we can do in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `outerHTML` property of the table first, then call the table element from `pandas`.

You need to wait for element to be visible. Use explicit wait like `WebdriverWait()`

```
driver.get('http://crdd.osdd.net/raghava/hemolytik/submitkey_browse.php?ran=1955')
table=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#example")))
tableRows=table.get_attribute("outerHTML")
df = pd.read_html(tableRows)[0]
print(df)
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
```

**Output:**

```
     ID      PMID  YEAR  ...                                 DSSP Natural Structure Final Structure
0   1643  16137634  2005  ...                     CCCCCCCCCCCSCCCC               NaN             NaN
1   1644  16137634  2005  ...                        CCTTSCCSSCCCC               NaN             NaN
2   1645  16137634  2005  ...                   CTTTCGGGHHHHHHHHCC               NaN             NaN
3   1646  16137634  2005  ...                   CGGGTTTHHHHHHHGGGC               NaN             NaN
4   1647  16137634  2005  ...                CCSCCCSSCHHHHHHHHHTTC               NaN             NaN
5   1910  16730859  2006  ...  CCCCCCCSSCCSHHHHHHHHTTHHHHHHHHSSCCC               NaN             NaN
6   1911  16730859  2006  ...                                CCSCC               NaN             NaN
7   1912  16730859  2006  ...                            CCSSSCSCC               NaN             NaN
8   1913  16730859  2006  ...       CCCSSCCSSCCSHHHHHTTHHHHTTTCSCC               NaN             NaN
9   1914  16730859  2006  ...                 CCSHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCC               NaN             NaN
10  2110  11226440  2001  ...              CCCSSCCCBTTBTSSSSSSCSCC               NaN             NaN
11  3799   9204560  1997  ...                               CCSSCC               NaN             NaN
12  4149  16137634  2005  ...                       CCHHHHHHHHHHHC               NaN             NaN

[13 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the shortest and happiest way of doing the work :)

Comment: what we can do if there is no `id` attribute for a specific page? for example when inspecting, we have this `<table summary="The result of Se", class="datatable"><tbody>...`

Comment: Use the class attribute. your css selector would be `table.datatable`

Comment: what if the table is long and is multi-pages? what I should look for inspection? and what changes should be done? I edited the question and put the sample link. Thanks

Comment: SO is used for research purpose. I would appreciate if you post a new question with your new requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select table by `@id` you need

```
driver.find_element_by_id("example")
```

By.CSS:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table#example")
```

By.XPATH:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='example'])
```

If you want to extract `@id` value you need

```
.get_attribute('id')
```

Since there is not much sense in searching by `@id` to extract that exact `@id` you might use other attribute of `table` node:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@aria-describedby='example_info']").get_attribute('id')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But once I am trying to run the `df = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@aria-describedby='example_info']").get_attribute('id'))[0]`, it raises an error, `ValueError: No tables found`.

Comment: @S.EB oops, sorry. I missed closing double-quotes. Try now